# ionic 2 native installation error

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, command-line-interface, native

i have this problem when write following code to install ionic-native

this is my code in ionic 2 file project

**sudo npm install ionic-native –save**

i got this error

npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/apple/Desktop/ionic/bluetooth/–save
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "ionic-native" "–save"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /Users/apple/Desktop/ionic/bluetooth/–save
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/apple/Desktop/ionic/bluetooth/–save'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/apple/Desktop/ionic/bluetooth/–save'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/Desktop/ionic/bluetooth/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `npm install @ionic-native/core --save`.
You don't need sudo.